# Is Delphi's Skewness correct

Tags: delphi, math, statistics

In Delphi one can calculate Skewness using `System.Math`'s function `MomentSkewKurtosis()`.

```
var m1, m2, m3, m4, skew, k: Extended;
System.Math.MomentSkewKurtosis([1.1,
  3.345,
  12.234,
  11.945,
  14.235,
  16.876,
  20.213,
  11.001,
  7.098,
  21.234], m1, m2, m3, m4, skew, k);
```

- This will prints skew equal to -0.200371489809269.
- Minitab prints the value -0.24
- SigmaXL prints the value -0.23611

The reason is that Delphi does not not perform adjustment.

Here is my implementation which calculates adjustment:

```
function Skewness(const X: array of Extended; const Adjusted: Boolean): Extended;
begin
  var AMean := Mean(X);
  var xi_minus_mean_power_3 := 0.0;
  var xi_minus_mean_power_2 := 0.0;
  for var i := Low(X) to High(X) do
  begin
    xi_minus_mean_power_3 := xi_minus_mean_power_3 + IntPower((X[i] - AMean), 3);
    xi_minus_mean_power_2 := xi_minus_mean_power_2 + IntPower((X[i] - AMean), 2);
  end;
  // URL : https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Descriptive-Statistics.html
  {                mean ((x - mean (x)).^3)
   skewness (X) = ------------------------.
                     std (x).^3
  }
  var N := Length(X);
  Result := xi_minus_mean_power_3 / N /
    IntPower(Sqrt(1 / N * xi_minus_mean_power_2), 3);
  // URL : https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Descriptive-Statistics.html
  {                  sqrt (N*(N-1))   mean ((x - mean (x)).^3)
  skewness (X, 0) = -------------- * ------------------------.
                        (N - 2)             std (x).^3
  }
  if Adjusted then
    Result := Result * Sqrt(N * Pred(N)) / (N - 2);
end;
```

The helper routine IntPower is as follows:

```
function IntPower(const X: Extended; const N: Integer): Extended;

  /// <remarks>
  /// Calculate any float to non-negative integer power. Developed by Rory Daulton and used with permission. Last modified December 1998.
  /// </remarks>
  function IntPow(const Base: Extended; const Exponent: LongWord): Extended;
    { Heart of Rory Daulton's IntPower: assumes valid parameters &
    non-negative exponent }
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  asm
      fld1                      // Result := 1
      cmp     eax, 0            // eax := Exponent
      jz      @@3
      fld     Base
      jmp     @@2
    @@1:    fmul    ST, ST      // X := Base * Base
    @@2:    shr     eax,1
      jnc     @@1
      fmul    ST(1),ST          // Result := Result * X
      jnz     @@1
      fstp    st                // pop X from FPU stack
    @@3:
      fwait
  end;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
  begin
    Result := Power(Base, Exponent);
  end;
  {$ENDIF}
begin
  if N = 0 then
    Result := 1
  else if (X = 0) then
  begin
    if N < 0 then
      raise EMathError.Create('Zero cannot be raised to a negative power.')
    else
      Result := 0
  end
  else if (X = 1) then
    Result := 1
  else if X = -1 then
  begin
    if Odd (N) then
      Result := -1
    else
      Result := 1
  end
  else if N > 0 then
    Result := IntPow (X, N)
  else
  begin
    var P: LongWord;
    if N <> Low (LongInt) then
      P := Abs(N)
    else
      P := LongWord(High(LongInt)) + 1;
    try
      Result := IntPow(X, P);
    except
      on EMathError do
      begin
        Result := IntPow(1 / X, P); // try again with another method, perhaps less precise
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    Result := 1 / Result;
  end;
end;
```

With that function the adjusted skewness becomes the accurate -0.237611357234441 matching Matlab and Minitab.

The only explanation I found is:
https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Descriptive-Statistics.html

> "The adjusted skewness coefficient is obtained by replacing the sample
> second and third central moments by their bias-corrected versions."

Same goes with Kurtosis:

```
function Kurtosis(const X: array of Extended; const Adjusted: Boolean): Extended;
begin
  var AMean := Mean(X);
  var xi_minus_mean_power_4 := 0.0;
  var xi_minus_mean_power_2 := 0.0;
  for var i := Low(X) to High(X) do
  begin
    xi_minus_mean_power_4 := xi_minus_mean_power_4 + IntPower((X[i] - AMean), 4);
    xi_minus_mean_power_2 := xi_minus_mean_power_2 + IntPower((X[i] - AMean), 2);
  end;

  {     mean ((x - mean (x)).^4)
  k1 = ------------------------
              std (x).^4
  }
  var N := Length(X);
  Result := xi_minus_mean_power_4 / N /
    IntPower(1 / N * xi_minus_mean_power_2, 2);
  {             N - 1
  k0 = 3 + -------------- * ((N + 1) * k1 - 3 * (N - 1))
           (N - 2)(N - 3)
  }
  if Adjusted then
    // Mathlab, Minitab and SigmaXL do not add 3 (which is the kurtosis for normal distribution
    Result := {3 + }(N - 1) / ((N - 2) * (N - 3)) * ((N + 1) * Result - 3 * (N - 1));
end;
```

What is the reason for such adjustments and why Delphi decided not to implement it?

Comment: Your `function Sknewness` cannot compile - please copy code instead of re-typing it. The parameter should be most likely `const X: TArray<Extended>`, too. Also check the outcome of the formattings of your question, especially on single linebreaks. Consider using lists and backticks.

Comment: This is a stats question and not a Delphi question or even a programming question. You can just read some standard stats texts to find the answer.

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan - that might be more reasonable indeed. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576232/why-adjustment-is-needed-when-calculating-skewness-and-kurtosis

Comment: The final question in your post is in two parts.  As David Heffernan has pointed out this is not the place to comment on the reason for making the adjustments.  The second part of your question, "Why Delphi decided not to implement it" is a Delphi question, but not a 'how to use' Delphi question, it should be directed to Delphi Product Management.  If you have an active subscription then contact support to raise a case.  You could also raise an issue on the Quality Portal https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa